# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0 after installing WindowsAzure.ServiceBus

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, azureservicebus

In ASP.NET MVC 5 application, when I update my WindowsAzure.ServiceBus nuget package to ver 3.4.6, I get the following error when the web application starts:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}

Is there a way to identify the problem and resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Web API? Could you provide your `packages.config` file for us to locate this issue? Also, there is a tutorial about troubleshooting the similar references issue, you could refer to [it](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2014/08/26/troubleshooting-nuget-references.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

> In ASP.NET MVC 5 application, when I update my WindowsAzure.ServiceBus nuget package to ver 3.4.6, I get the following error when the web application starts

As I known, the [Microsoft Azure Service Bus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/3.4.0) has no any dependencies after version 3.1.4, while the prior version may depend on `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager`, and both libraries do not depend on `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`. Please try to downgrade WindowsAzure.ServiceBus to your previous version to isolate this issue.

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}

According to your description, I tried to reproduce this issue and did not encounter this issue. Please try to clean your project and restore your NuGet packages. Also, please follow the suggestion in my comment to locate this issue. Additionally, there are some similar issues, you could refer to them ([issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408167/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-4-0-0-0-culture-neutr) and [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982682/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-4-0-0-0-with-asp-net-m)).