# ASP.NET Web API 2 available since when?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Since which version of Visual Studio is ASP.NET **Web API 2** available?

In particular I need the IHttpActionResult interface.

I could not find such information on Microsoft online documentation. I can only infer it has been introduced since VS 2013, but only because all the pages I saw had that as a minimum version.

Comment: As asp.net web api 2 is officially a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/) the only dependency is the running a version of visual studio that supports the minimum supported framework for web api 2 as well as being able to connect to nuget to retrieve the package.

Comment: @Igor - Do you know which this version is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21572891/1260204. So probably any version of VS that supports .net 4.5 and later (vs 2012 and later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asp.net web api 2 is officially a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/) the only dependency is the running a version of visual studio that supports the minimum supported framework for web api 2 as well as being able to connect to nuget to retrieve the package.

- [Web API 2 is supported on .net 4.5 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572891/1260204).
- [VS2012 and later supports targeting .net 4.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jasonz/2012/08/15/visual-studio-2012-and-net-framework-4-5-released-to-the-web/), so this is the absolute minimum version of VS you can use and make use of web api v2.

You might have to install [web tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532) to be able to develop against web api v2 though. See [this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21668403/1260204).